# How to call a Spring MVC controller by ui:include?

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, facelets

I am working on a legacy project that was built with JSP. The JSP page included an HTML page via `<jsp:include>`. But the included page was essentially a mapping to a Spring MVC controller.

Now I switched to JSF and replaced the `<jsp:include>` with a `<ui:include>`. But now, the call to the Spring MVC servlet does not work anymore.

Obviously there is a difference between `<jsp:include>` and `<ui:include>` of JSF. Does anybody know, how I can call a spring MVC component in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

For now, we solved this by using JQuery's load method to call the SpringMVC servlet. We refrained using ui:include for now.